# Bash loop, user creation, create files

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I'm still learning the basics of Linux. For a class I need to do a script that create user in a text file with this format: Name,Rank (next row). but this script is giving me some errors. I have the mkdir operator missing error!
Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/root/Bureau/Utilisateur-Linux.txt"
while IFS= read -r var
do
    echo $var |cut -d',' -f1 | read nom
    echo $var |cut -d',' -f2 | read rang
    useradd `$nom`
    cd /data
    mkdir `$nom`
    chown $nom /data/`$nom`
    if  [ `$rang` -eq "Superviseur" ]
    then
        groupadd `$rang`
    elif  [ `$rang` -eq "Technicien" ]
    then
        groupadd `$rang`
    elif  [ `$rang` -eq "Client" ]
    then
        groupadd `$rang`
    fi
done < "$file"
```

Comment: You aren't using $file anywhere. `done` probably missing `< "$file"`.

Comment: I'm new to this, where should I add it? it's the path to the files with the name and rank!

Comment: Which errors are you getting? Please add them to your question.

Comment: I've added the error.

Comment: You have multiple errors in your script. It's hard to help you debug all of them. Suggest you take a step back and test a few lines at a time. Here are some suggestions/tips. Add `set -x` at the top of your script to enable debugging. Your use of backtick `\`` looks wrong. The backtick syntax causes the variable to be expanded and *executed*.